Middleware function not fetching data from external resources in Next.js production
I’ve created a middleware function in Next.js to control and protect sensitive pages in my application. Locally, the middleware works as expected and fetches user data using the middlewareAuth function. However, when I deploy the application, the middlewareAuth function doesn’t fetch data from external resources.
Here’s the relevant code:
src/middleware.js
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";

export async function middleware(req, context) {
  const url = req.url;
  const pathname = req.nextUrl.pathname;
  let user = {};

  if (pathname.startsWith("/profile")) {
    context.waitUntil(
      middlewareAuth(req).then((res) => {
        user = res;
        console.log("Data:", res);
      })
    );
    if (!user) return NextResponse.redirect(new URL("/auth", url));
  }
  if (pathname.startsWith("/cart")) {
    context.waitUntil(
      middlewareAuth(req).then((res) => {
        user = res;
        console.log("Data in middleware:", res?.role);
        console.log(user?.role !== "ADMIN");
      })
    );
    // console.log("user-cart:", user);
    if (!user) return NextResponse.redirect(new URL("/auth", url));
  }
  if (pathname.startsWith("/admin")) {
    context.waitUntil(
      middlewareAuth(req).then((res) => {
        user = res;
        console.log("Data:", res);
      })
    );
    if (!user) return NextResponse.redirect(new URL("/auth", url));
    if (user && user?.role !== "ADMIN")
      return NextResponse.redirect(new URL("/", url));
  }
  return NextResponse.next();
}

export const config = {
  matcher: ["/admin/:path*", "/profile/:path*", "/cart/:path*"],
};

and the middlewareAuth.js as follow:
import { toStringCookies } from "./toStringCookies";

export async function middlewareAuth(req) {
  const baseURL = `${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_URL}`;
  const { data } = await fetch(`${baseURL}/user/profile`, {
    method: "GET",
    credentials: "include",
    headers: {
      Cookie: toStringCookies(req.cookies),
    },
  }).then((res) => res.json());
  const { user } = data || {};
  // console.log("data in middleware:", data);
  return user;
}


I suspect this issue might be related to the middleware being an edge function. Any suggestions on how to troubleshoot or fix this problem?
